# Starting a Script at System Boot on AIX 7

Tags: shell-script, boot, aix

I want to know how can I start a script at the system startup.
I tried to make a sh file under ***/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/*** but I rebooted the OS and it does not start my script as I want.

Comment: What is your default runlevel? `awk -F: '$3 == "initdefault" { print $2 }' /etc/inittab`

Answer (score 1):

To add entries to the system inittab, use `mkitab`:

```
sudo mkitab 'myapp1:2:respawn:/path/to/myapp1'
sudo mkitab 'myapp2:2:wait:/path/to/myapp2'
sudo mkitab 'myapp3:2:once:/path/to/myapp3'
sudo mkitab 'myapp4:2:boot:/path/to/myapp4'
sudo mkitab 'myapp5:2:bootwait:/path/to/myapp5'
```

Where the various `Action` options are (most usefully):

> respawn
>
> If the process identified in this record does not exist, start the process. If the process currently exists, do nothing and continue scanning the /etc/inittab file.
>
> wait
>
> When the init command enters the run level specified for this record, start the process and wait for it to stop. While the init command is in the same run level, all subsequent reads of the /etc/inittab file ignore this object.
>
> once
>
> When the init command enters the run level specified for this record, start the process, do not wait for it to stop and when it does stop do not restart the process. If the system enters a new run level while the process is running, the process is not restarted.
>
> boot
>
> Read this record only when the system boots and reads the /etc/inittab file. The init command starts the process. Do not wait for the process to stop and when it does stop, do not restart the process. The run level for this process should be the default, or it must match the run level specified by the init command at startup time.
>
> bootwait
>
> Read this record only when the system boots and reads the /etc/inittab file. The init command starts the process. Wait for it to stop, and when it does stop, do not restart the process.

Reference:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mkitab.htm

Comment: I will try with your example and letting you know about if it will work.

Comment: @vicdeveloper, did it turn out OK?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to point `inittab` to the script, but you should use the tools available to do that versus manually editing.

```
man mkitab
```

Comment: An example of how to execute a sh file using this method ?.

Comment: mkitab "label:once:sh /scripts/script.sh"

Comment: change "once" to "wait" if you want the script to complete before proceeding to next line in inittab